# Encountering 'Invalid package.json' error in Yarn, how to resolve?

Tags: frontend, developer-tools

Issue:
I'm encountering an error with Yarn, displaying "Usage Error: Invalid package.json in ../../../../package.json" when running yarn commands. This issue is present in two out of three projects. The package.json files appear to be correct.

Troubleshooting Steps Attempted:

Executed yarn and yarn -v, and various other yarn commands.
Request for Assistance:
How can I identify and resolve the "Invalid package.json" issue in my projects? What could be causing this error?